# Apache 2.4 Basic Authentication Requested twice for every page load

Tags: apache-2.4

Every page load I am being asked for my password twice... And I am not sure why...

Here is my directory definition

```
 <Directory "/var/www/html">
      AllowOverride All
      AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
      AuthName "Please Log In"
      AuthType Basic
      Require valid-user
 </Directory>
```

Any ideas on why I would be requested to enter my password for every page load? And why every page load is requesting my password twice?

Comment: What's in the access log?

Comment: 401 for the url, then I login, and then 200, what should I be looking for?

Comment: Include the relevant log entries in the question.